# How to calculate a column in a data table or frame based on table information in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I am trying to create a new column in a data frame or table in R using values from the table. For example, below is a table:

```
RowID| Col1   | Col2 |
----------------------
1    | apple  | cow  |
2    | orange | dog  |
3    | apple  | cat  |
4    | cherry | fish |
5    | cherry | ant  |
6    | apple  | rat  |
```

I want add an extra column to this table. This column checks to see what other rows have the same value in col1, and prints out a concatenated string with the values of col3 for these rows. IE:

```
RowID| Col1   | Col2 | newCol
------------------------------
1    | apple  | cow  | cat,rat   (Row 3 & 6 match col1 values)
2    | orange | dog  | na        (No rows match this col1 value)
3    | apple  | cat  | cow,rat   (Row 1 & 6 match col1 values)
4    | cherry | fish | ant       (Row 5 matches col1 values)
5    | cherry | ant  | fish      (Row 4 matches col1 values)
6    | apple  | rat  | cow,cat   (Row 1 & 3 match col1 values)
```

So to reiterate. We check to see what other rows have the same value in column one. Once you find these rows, you grab their col2 value, concatenate them together, and make that the result of the row whose col1 we were comparing against.

I've been trying for the past couple days to figure it and simply cannot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat$newCol <- Map(function(x, y) dat[dat$Col1 == y & dat$RowID != x, "Col2"],
                  dat$RowID, dat$Col1)

dat

#   RowID   Col1 Col2   newCol
# 1     1  apple  cow cat, rat
# 2     2 orange  dog         
# 3     3  apple  cat cow, rat
# 4     4 cherry fish      ant
# 5     5 cherry  ant     fish
# 6     6  apple  rat cow, cat
```

(Where `dat` is:

```
dat <- read.table(text =
"RowID| Col1   | Col2 |
1    | apple  | cow  |
2    | orange | dog  |
3    | apple  | cat  |
4    | cherry | fish |
5    | cherry | ant  |
6    | apple  | rat  |
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)[, -4]
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works without need of row IDs. It makes use of `data.table` internal row numbering `.I`.

```
F <- c("x", "y", "x", "z", "x", "y")
V <- c("dog", "cat", "monkey", "cow", "cat", "lion")

library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(F, V)
print(dt)

   F      V
1: x    dog
2: y    cat
3: x monkey
4: z    cow
5: x    cat
6: y   lion

grasp <- function(id, data=data) {
    subset <- data[ ,.I==id]
    level <- data[subset,F]
    x <- data[!subset][F==level, V]
    return (paste(x, collapse=", "))
}

dt[ ,newCol:=lapply(.I, grasp, data=dt)]
print(dt)

   F      V      newCol
1: x    dog monkey, cat
2: y    cat        lion
3: x monkey    dog, cat
4: z    cow            
5: x    cat dog, monkey
6: y   lion         cat
```